# WindowsFormsHost Controls - Exception Handling

Tags: .net, wpf, exception, windowsformshost

I have a WPF Window which requires several WindowsFormHost controls. I noticed that if I model the control like this, then Exceptions do not bubble to the surface and are silently handled i.e. only visible using SharpDevelop's Debugging option 'Pause on handled Exceptions'.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

I have tested this by throwing an exception in the Window's Loaded Event Handler code. If I comment out one of the WindowsFormsHost controls, exception handling is as normal and the code breaks, but if left as shown in the code below, the Window is displayed as if the exception was caught.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Window
        x:Class="TEST.Window1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TEST"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition
                    Height="150" />
                <RowDefinition
                    Height="150" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
    </Window>

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window1_Loaded);
    }

    void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("TEST");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a 64-bit WinForms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-64-bit-winforms-applicatio)

Comment: @Hans Passant, 'Im using 32bit windows xp, compiler has been set to optimise for x86 processors.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the intermediary windows interop stack that the WindowsFormsHost creates to hande Windows Messages for Windows Forms technology.

It's based on an almost standard [NativeWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) class, and unfortunately, this class just eats exception by default. You can have a look at it using Reflector or any other IL inspection tool. The heart of this class is this method:

```
private IntPtr Callback(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
{
    try
    {
        // process message
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        this.OnThreadException(exception);
    }
    ...
}
```

By default, the [OnThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.onthreadexception.aspx) method is ... empty. In theory you could create a class that derives from WindowsFormsHost, especially the [BuildWindowCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.buildwindowcore.aspx) method. I've tried to do it, but it does not work as WindowsFormsHost implementation uses a lot of private stuf....